# Basic questions about finding a volume formula for a box inside of an ellipsoid,

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, volume, lagrange-multiplier

I want to maximize the volume of a box, with sides parallel to the $xy$, $xz$ and $yz$-planes, with the box inside of an ellipsoid

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$$

So, my answer, using Lagrange multipliers, turns out to be wrong, at least comparing my work to the solution given.

I had thought to maximize "length times height times width", so I figured that the objective function should be $f(x,y,z)=xyxzyz = x^2y^2z^2$.

The solution instead maximizes a different function:  $f(x,y,z) = 2x2y2z$

I am guessing that the solution is indeed correct?  And the point I probably missed was this: the ellipsoid is centered at $0$.  So, sketching out the box on paper, "length times height times width" *does* look like $2x 2y 2z$.

What do you think?

Also, how does an equation of an ellipsoid not centered at $0$ look like?  Would it be something like this:

$$\frac{(x-1)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y-2)^2}{b^2} + \frac{(z-3)^2}{c^2}=1?$$

...would this be an ellipsoid centered at $(1,2,3)$?

Sorry for the simple questions - my geometric intuition is a bit weak.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @user170231, thanks so much for your quick response.  Ok, so now I know the general formula for the ellipsoid.  And right...I am a little confused about the objective function, and perhaps the solution's motivation was that the box is centered at the origin, and so the three different edge lengths would be twice the length of x, y...z.  Perhaps the objective function (xyz) that you mentioned would make more sense if we knew the box was on the first octant only, but then again...I doubt it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct equation for the ellispoid centered at the origin is

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} +\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1.$$

It is obvious that the resulting (optimal) box would be centered at the origin.

If we denote one of the vertices of the box by $(x,y,z)$, then the sides have lengths

$$2x,\ 2y,\ 2z$$ assuming $x,y,z>0$.
With this,  the volume is $8xyz$.

Comment: Right, @GaussTheBauss, in hindsight, two additional things I should have sketched on paper, the ellipsoid that circumscribes the box, and then fixing a vertex like you had suggested; then the objective function is easily seen to be $2x2y2z$ ... I'll re-do the problem now - thanks for your answer :-)

Comment: (Naively, I sketched the box in the first octant only... @GuassTheBauss ...)

Comment: @user301608 My pleasure. Mistakes like that happen all the time. If you are satisfied with the answer, It would be helpful if you accept it :) And Welcome to MSE!

Comment: Thanks so much - just accepted :-)

Comment: Why is it obvious that the box would also be centered in the origin?

Comment: @SeñorBilly You downvoted the accepted answer for this?! You are truly an incredible specimen.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't thinking straight in that moment. I was thinking in "why does the box have sides parallel to the axes? ...but it's in the question. Do a dummy edit and I'll be happy to un-downvote you.

Comment: @SeñorBilly done.

Answer (score 0):

A dimension check would’ve told you that your expression for the volume of the inscribed box was incorrect. A volume should have a dimension of $\text{length}^3$, but $x^2y^2z^2$ has a dimension of $\text{length}^6$.

As user170231 commented, your equation for an ellipsoid centered somewhere other than the origin is correct. Note that the axes of this translated ellipsoid are still parallel to the coordinate axes.

Comment: Hi @amd, ok got it - thanks so much for your answer :-)